# django model save to several tables

Tags: django

The save method saves instance into two different tables, AgencyBeforeReg and Agency, i have a problem saving Services field which is manyToMany field, how can it be done?

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
        if self.id and self.active:
            self.sign = 'f'
        if not self.active:
            self.sign = 'c'
            self.deactivate_date = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(AgencyBeforeReg, self).save(force_insert, force_update, using)
        agency = Agency.objects.create(
            id=self.id,
            unpf=self.unpf,
            unp=self.unp,
            egr=self.egr,
            title=self.title,
            reg_date=self.reg_date,
            reg_organ=self.reg_organ,
            post_index=self.post_index,
            place=self.place,
            office=self.office,
            # services=self.services,
            ins_date=self.ins_date,
            edit_date=self.edit_date
        )

        agency.services.add()
```

Answer (score 0):

I haved same problem a few days ago. Many-To-Many field is saving not like others. You need to set services after saving, code will looks like this

```
agency = Agency.objects.create(
        id=self.id,
        unpf=self.unpf,
        unp=self.unp,
        egr=self.egr,
        title=self.title,
        reg_date=self.reg_date,
        reg_organ=self.reg_organ,
        post_index=self.post_index,
        place=self.place,
        office=self.office,
        ins_date=self.ins_date,
        edit_date=self.edit_date
    )
agency.save()
for service in self.services:
      agency.services.add(service)
```

in my case it's work fine.

Comment: after doing this? i get 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Comment: for service in self.services.all():
      agency.services.add(service) - this way i get empty list